# How to increase the icon text size in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, fonts, .desktop

How can I increase the icon text size in Ubuntu 18.04? I have tried
using `gnome-tweaks` but I was only able to change font size of window titles and interface items.

Here is a screen shot of three icons from my desktop and I want to change the font size of the text below each icon.

[image]

Comment: Hi, you want to change the font size of texts below the icons on "Desktop" only??

Comment: Preferably, I would like to change the icon text font size everywhere.

Comment: it is possible to select the text below the icons on Desktop, others are related with "Interface" in gnome-tweaks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Open dconf Editor. If not yet installed, install it by the following command in terminal.
   `sudo apt update && sudo apt-get install dconf-editor -y`
2. search with keywords nautilus, open /org/gnome/nautilus/
3. open Desktop and then choose font (Desktop font)
4. give your preferred value.

please see the below pics, where i changed font sizes from 'sans normal' 5,10,15 & 20

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]